# Is there a more elegant way to write the score function for an NxN array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a score function which correctly evaluates the following NxN arrays:

```
    int state1[][] = { 
            {0, 1, 0},
            {1, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 0} };  // score = 0

    int state2[][] = { 
            {0, 1, 1},
            {1, 0, 0},
            {1, 1, 0} };  // score = 2

    int state3[][] = { 
            {1, 1, 0},
            {1, 1, 1},
            {1, 0, 0} };  // score = 5
```

Is there a more elegant (simpler) way to write the following score function?

```
public static int score(int[][] s) {
    int count = 0;
    int hold = 0;
    int length = s.length;
    int end = length - 1;
    for (int col = 0; col < length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < length; row++) {
            hold = s[row][col];
            if (row == 0 && hold == 1 && s[row + 1][col] == 1) {
                count++;
            }
            else if (row == end && hold == 1 && s[row - 1][col] == 1) {
                count++;
            }
            else if (row != 0 && row != end && hold == 1 && (s[row + 1][col] == 1 || s[row - 1][col] == 1)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Let me add that scoring depends on if a "1" has another "1" immediately above or below it. In other words, if a "1" is in row 1, the score in incremented if there is a "1" in the same column in either row 0 OR row 2.

Comment: Describe what does the function do?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask for help in improving working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this will do the same thing - to be tested:

```
if (hold == 1) {
  boolean hasOneAbove = row > 0 && s[row - 1][col] == 1;
  boolean hasOneBelow = row < end && s[row + 1][col] == 1;
  if (hasOneAbove || hasOneBelow) count++;
}
```

Comment: Yepper, this snippet of code works in place of my if-else-if block. Of course, in hindsight, it is logically straightforward compared to my roundabout code. I just need more practice so that I can more easily identify similar strategies.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the same:

```
public static int score(int[][] s) {
    int count = 0;
    final int end = s.length - 1;
    for (int col = 0; col <= end; col++)
        for (int row = 0; row <= end; row++)
            if (s[row][col] == 1)
                if ((row != end && s[row + 1][col] == 1) || (row != 0 && s[row - 1][col] == 1))
                    count++;
    return count;
}
```